# Force casting an object literal

Tags: typescript

I have the following code exporting a const

```
export const sqsEventMock : SQSEvent = {
  Records: [
    {
      body: 'sample body',
      messageAttributes: {
        EventType: {
          dataType: 'String',
          stringValue: 'MyCustomEvent'
        },
        StreamName: {
          dataType: 'String',
          stringValue: 'input-stream'
        },
        version: 1337,
        correlationId: 'fake-correlation-id',
        source: 'fake-source'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

However I am unable to force cast this const to an SQSEvent in AWS.  I can of-course expose a function instead of a direct const, but I prefer to do it this anyway.  Does anyone know how to do this.  I cannot use `Partial` here because there is another method further down the code which requires a `SQSEvent` instead of a `Partial<SQSEvent>`

Comment: If some code requires the full struct, why don't you generate the full struct?

Comment: Have you tried casting the object `as unknown as SQSEvent`? Only do this if you're Really Sure You Want To

Comment: I am actually doing it on the original calling code, but is there any way I can do it on the const itself?